# percent encoding URL with python

Tags: python, url, encoding

When I enter a URL into maps.google.com such as https://dl.dropbox.com/u/94943007/file.kml , it will encode this URL into:

```
https:%2F%2Fdl.dropbox.com%2Fu%2F94943007%2Ffile.kml
```

I am wondering what is this encoding called and is there a way to encode a URL like this using python?

I tried this:

The process is called [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding):

```
>>> urllib.quote('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/94943007/file.kml', '')
'https%3A%2F%2Fdl.dropbox.com%2Fu%2F94943007%2Ffile.kml'
```

but did not get the expected results:

```
'https%3A//dl.dropbox.com/u/94943007/file.kml'
```

what i need is this:

```
https:%2F%2Fdl.dropbox.com%2Fu%2F94943007%2Ffile.kml
```

**how do i encode this URL properly?**

the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/

states:

> All characters to be URL-encoded are encoded using a '%' character and
>   a two-character hex value corresponding to their UTF-8 character. For
>   example, 上海+中國 in UTF-8 would be URL-encoded as
>   %E4%B8%8A%E6%B5%B7%2B%E4%B8%AD%E5%9C%8B. The string ? and the
>   Mysterians would be URL-encoded as %3F+and+the+Mysterians.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
urllib.quote_plus(url, safe=':')
```

Since you don't want the colon encoded you need to specify that when calling `urllib.quote()`:

```
>>> expected = 'https:%2F%2Fdl.dropbox.com%2Fu%2F94943007%2Ffile.kml'
>>> url = 'https://dl.dropbox.com/u/94943007/file.kml'
>>> urllib.quote(url, safe=':') == expected
True
```

`urllib.quote()` takes a keyword argument `safe` that defaults to `/` and indicates which characters are considered safe and therefore don't need to be encoded. In your first example you used `''` which resulted in the slashes being encoded. The unexpected output you pasted below where the slashes weren't encoded probably was from a previous attempt where you didn't set the keyword argument `safe` at all.

Overriding the default of `'/'` and instead excluding the colon with `':'` is what finally yields the desired result.

**Edit**: Additionally, the API calls for spaces to be encoded as plus signs. Therefore `urllib.quote_plus()` should be used (whose keyword argument `safe` doesn't default to `'/'`).

Comment: Note that this does not deal with the lack of escaping that OP was expecting.

Comment: @Marcin, I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Are you referring to `%xx` escapes or something else?

Comment: I downvoted this because it did not at the time make explicit its results or how it would resolve *all* of the issues identified by OP. It could still use an explanation of how it achieves the desired outcome.

Comment: Oh, I see. I edited my answer to explain a little bit better what's going on.