# Google http://maps.google.com/maps/geo query with non-english characters

Tags: python, google-maps, urllib, google-geocoding-api

I'm creating a Python (using `urllib2`) parser of addresses with non-english characters in it. The goal is to find coordinates of every address.

When I open this url in **Firefox**:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=Czech%20Republic%2010000%20Male%C5%A1ice&output=csv
```

it is converted (changes in address box) to

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=Czech Republic 10000 Malešice&output=csv
```

and returns

```
200,6,50.0865113,14.4918052
```

which is a **correct** result.

However, if I open the same url (encoded, with %20 and such) in **`urllib2`** (or Opera browser), the result is

```
200,4,49.7715220,13.2955410
```

which is **incorrect**. How can I open the first url in `urllib2` to get the "`200,6,50.0865113,14.4918052`" result?

**Edit:**

Code used

```
import urllib2

psc = '10000'
name = 'Malešice'
url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%s&output=csv' % urllib2.quote('Czech Republic %s %s' % (psc, name))

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = response.read()

print 'Parsed url %s, result %s\n' % (url, data)
```

output

`Parsed url http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=Czech%20Republic%2010000%20Male%C5%A1ice&output=csv, result 200,4,49.7715220,13.2955410`

Comment: Could you specify the exact line of code with urllib2.open please (as you try)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [percent encoding URL with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114853/percent-encoding-url-with-python/12114958) (for use with Google Maps API).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this behavior, and at first I was dumbfounded as to why it's happening. Closer inspection of the HTTP requests with [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) showed that the requests sent by Firefox (not surprisingly) contain a couple more HTTP-Headers.

In the end it turned out it's the **`Accept-Language`** header that makes the difference. You only get the correct result if

- an `Accept-Language` header is set
- **and** it has a non-english language listed first (the priorities don't seem to matter)

So, for example this `Accept-Language` header works:

```
headers = {'Accept-Language': 'de-ch,en'}
```

To summarize, modified like this your code works for me:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2

psc = '10000'
name = 'Malešice'
url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%s&output=csv' % urllib2.quote('Czech Republic %s %s' % (psc, name))
headers = {'Accept-Language': 'de-ch,en'}

req = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
data = response.read()

print 'Parsed url %s, result %s\n' % (url, data)
```

**Note**: In my opinion, this is a bug in Google's geocoding API. The `Accept-Language` header indicates what languages the user agent prefers the content in, but it shouldn't have any effect on how the request is interpreted.