# Downloading Images with "illegal" characters

Tags: image, download, bulk

I am migrating a shop over for a client.

I have to pull all the old image files off her 'shop' which has no FTP access.

It allowed me to export a list of filenames/urls. My plan was to load them up in Firefox and use "Downloadthemall" to simply download all the files. (Around 2000). However about 1 1/3 have [ and ] in.

i.e.

cdn.crapshop.com/images/image[1].jpg

Downloadthemall freaks out and only reads it as

cdn.crapshop.com/images/image

And won't download it because it isn't a file.

Anyone got any ideas of an alternative way to pull a list like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this solution that explains why the example URL you provided is invalid: [Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid). After you look at that post you'll see that, in the answer provided by @good, you have to encode characters that are not according to the specification using percent encoding, so the webserver will understand them.

This calls for python... see this post: [Percent encoding in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114853/percent-encoding-url-with-python)

And then we can put it all together in a script, which you will use to read from stdin and output to stdout: `python script.py < input > output.out`.

```
import urllib, sys

while 1:
    try:
        line = sys.stdin.readline()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

    if not line:
        break

    print urllib.quote(line.strip(), safe=':').strip('\'')
```

Then, hopefully, download them all will parse that list of files (the input to that script is supposed to be a list of url's separated by a newline) that have been corrected by the script.

You may be interested in this post as well: [Downloading files with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862173/how-to-download-a-file-using-python-in-a-smarter-way). Which shows you how to download files (web pages in particular) using python.

Good luck!